# Condition formatting dates two week before the actual target date

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet in excel with a formula that when I enter a date into column A cells, column B cells will enter a date 9 months - 1 day from the date entered in cell A1, A2, A3, etc... Now I would like to write a conditional format that will cause cell B1, B2, B3, etc... to turn red two week (14 days) before the date which came up in cell B1, B2, B3, etc... Only the dates two week before the date(s) in column B would turn red.

Answer (score 1):

Check if cell is blank AND if today is 14 days away from the date in b1.

1. Select the B column
2. Select conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a Formula...
3. =AND((B1-TODAY()<14),(NOT(ISBLANK(B1))))
4. Select Fill Style for red